# Verify that $P(t)=P_0e^{kt}$, $t>0$ is a solution of $\frac{dP}{dt}=kP.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A city has a growing population at a rate proportional to the current population, that is:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=kP.$$

Verify that $P(t)=P_0e^{kt}$, $t>0$ is a solution of the equation.

There is more to the question which I have completed, but this first part is confusing me. Could someone explain please.

Comment: well compute $P'(t)$ (the derivative of $P(t)$ with respect to $t$)... and see what happens. Hint: $\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\alpha t})=\alpha e^{\alpha t}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, differentiate the solution and see if it satisfies the equation:

In other words, can you obtain $\frac{dP}{dt} = kP$ from $ P(t) = P_{0}e^{kt}$?

$$ P(t) = P_{0}e^{kt}$$

$$ \frac{dP}{dt} = P_{0}ke^{kt} = k(P_{0}e^{kt})= kP$$

Comment: @Bruh, you're very welcome and good luck with the rest of the question!